# Solution for making flash animation without grainy look?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, animation, gif, adobe-flash

I copy pasted a design made from Illustrator to Flash CS6 and when I export as an animated gif, I get a grainy image. Any solutions to making a flash animation convert to animated gif without loss in quality?

Comment: Turn off the dither.

Comment: How are you exporting your work? I'm not super accustomed to Flash but coming from After Effects and wanting to export gifs I usually go through Photoshop and its "Save for Web and Devices" feature. That lets me fine tune the controls to my liking in order to compress the gif file more/less.

Comment: Exporting from File > export as video and then changing the file format to animated gif. Rafael, dither was always turned off. I believe I got my solution by increasing the DPI and then just shrinking the image size when I paste it somewhere.